# Curve described by a pendulum of variable length

Tags: classical-mechanics

Imagine an ideal pendulum who's length can change arbitrarily throughout its motion. Does the length of the curve described by the bob during the descent phase of the pendulum's oscillation always equal the length of the curve described by the bob during the corresponding ascent phase?

Assume that the bob never swings past vertical, i.e. the pendulum circles its origin. Also assume that the pendulum uses a fix rod, meaning any change in pendulum length is instantaneously realized by the bob.

Comment: If the length changes "arbitrarily", why would there be any particular relationship between the arclengths in the two phases?

Comment: This is not an energy conserving system, which means that the amplitude of the oscillation can change, so... no. Simple corner case: the bob is fully horizontal and retracts immediately to the center. At that point the motion stops completely.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This system is called a "parametric pendulum" (at least that's how I interpret the description). There are some very nice explanations and videos on the internet.